# How to configure k8s (GKE) to pull images from docker-registry-proxy

Tags: docker, kubernetes, proxy, google-kubernetes-engine, docker-registry

I have one global container registry.
I will have many k8s clusters in different cloud providers. For now I use GKE.
I want to have in each k8s cluster a local docker registry cache. It reduces the pulling latency and I will be safer if the global container registry has short downtime.

It should work like: when I deploy something on k8s cluster, the k8s starts pulling the image and goes via this proxy. If this proxy already has this image it will serve it quickly, if not it will pull it from the global container registry and will serve it.

I tried to setup https://hub.docker.com/r/rpardini/docker-registry-proxy
I run it, but I can't configure k8s cluster to use it as a proxy. In docs I see how to do it, but it is ok when you have your own k8s clusters on servers and you can change dockerd or containerd service files, but I have managed k8s in Google Cloud (GKE), so I can't easily permanent change files on nodes.

Do you have any ideas on how to achieve what I want?

Comment: Hi there! What about Nexus from Sonatype or JFrog Repo? I think that Nexus can do what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for comment @ArmandoCuevas. 
I don't want to change my container registry. It works fine. So this is not a problem with container registry. 
I want to have proxy/cache for container registry in each k8s cluster to reduce latency and be prepared for short downtime of our global container registry.

Comment: Hi there. Nexus and JFrog repos allows you to work as a proxy registry.

Comment: have you followed this guide? https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: I guess you would need to have your images specified like `<registry proxy service>/image:tag` in k8s manifests